# Which distributed transaction coordinator WCF uses for transactions

Tags: wcf, transactions, distributed, coordinate

I understand that MSDTC(Microsoft Distributed transaction coordinator) WCF uses to manage its distributed transaction but If WCF service perform some database operation on Oracle or File System will this same coordinator will work and if no which it will be and can we choose wcf coordinator for our wcf service

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19078358/745969)....